# What is the Windows XP equivalent of inet_pton or InetPton?

Tags: c++, c, windows-xp, ip, ip-address

I need to determine whether a particular string is a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address literal. If I understand correctly, the correct way to do this on POSIX systems is to use `inet_pton` to convert it into a network address structure and see if it succeeds. Windows Vista and later have `InetPton` which does essentially the same thing. But as far as I can tell, Windows XP doesn't declare either of those, and I need to be able to do this correctly on XP. So, the question is what system function to use to do this?

Worst case, I can write a function to parse it myself, but I'd prefer a standard, system function which has therefore been thoroughly tested and properly handles all corner cases and whatnot. It's already bad enough that Microsoft couldn't just declare `inet_pton` like everyone else and went with `InetPton` for their newer OSes.

Comment: Try [WSAAddressToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741516(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 11):

In windows XP you can use these functions:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>


int inet_pton(int af, const char *src, void *dst)
{
  struct sockaddr_storage ss;
  int size = sizeof(ss);
  char src_copy[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN+1];

  ZeroMemory(&ss, sizeof(ss));
  /* stupid non-const API */
  strncpy (src_copy, src, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN+1);
  src_copy[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] = 0;

  if (WSAStringToAddress(src_copy, af, NULL, (struct sockaddr *)&ss, &size) == 0) {
    switch(af) {
      case AF_INET:
    *(struct in_addr *)dst = ((struct sockaddr_in *)&ss)->sin_addr;
    return 1;
      case AF_INET6:
    *(struct in6_addr *)dst = ((struct sockaddr_in6 *)&ss)->sin6_addr;
    return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

const char *inet_ntop(int af, const void *src, char *dst, socklen_t size)
{
  struct sockaddr_storage ss;
  unsigned long s = size;

  ZeroMemory(&ss, sizeof(ss));
  ss.ss_family = af;

  switch(af) {
    case AF_INET:
      ((struct sockaddr_in *)&ss)->sin_addr = *(struct in_addr *)src;
      break;
    case AF_INET6:
      ((struct sockaddr_in6 *)&ss)->sin6_addr = *(struct in6_addr *)src;
      break;
    default:
      return NULL;
  }
  /* cannot direclty use &size because of strict aliasing rules */
  return (WSAAddressToString((struct sockaddr *)&ss, sizeof(ss), NULL, dst, &s) == 0)?
          dst : NULL;
}
```

That's it. Link with ws2_32 library.

Comment: Note that you will need a call to WSAStartup to initialize winsock2.

Answer (score 5):

> But as far as I can tell, Windows XP doesn't declare either of those, and I need to be able to do this correctly on XP.

**[InetPton documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc805844.aspx)** states the following requirements:

- **Minimum supported client:** Windows Vista [desktop apps only]
- **Minimum supported server:** Windows Server 2008 [desktop apps only]

> Worst case, I can write a function to parse it myself, but I'd prefer a standard, system function which has therefore been thoroughly tested and properly handles all corner cases and whatnot.

How about relying of a portion of code from the OSS network tool **[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)**?

You can find their reimplementation of **inet_pton** in their **[source code repository](https://github.com/wireshark/wireshark/blob/90644c83725f979f82e7990792faaf6e847f74ea/wsutil/inet_pton.c)**.

The licence (see below) is very permissive, so that may be a good alternative.

> Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this software for any
>   purpose with or without fee is hereby granted, provided that the above
>   copyright notice and this permission notice appear in all copies.

Answer (score 3):

Looking through the SDK header files I find `inet_pton()` declared in 
"c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Include\WS2tcpip.h".  `InetPton` is only a #define to that.

So, it seems MS is providing the proper interface after all, but only starting with Vista.  But XP has no IPv6 support that is worth mentioning, if I recall correctly.

The other choice is to wrap it yourself with two calls to `WSAAddressToString()`, one with `AF_INET`, one with `AF_INET6`.  I'm guessing here from the docs, haven't tried it.