# error in mingw while compiling socket proram on windows

Tags: c, sockets, mingw

I've getting this error on mingw:
pr1.c is the filename

I faced some problems and then added library like this, but now getting these errors:

```
$ gcc pr1.c -o pr1.exe -lwsock32 -lws2_32

pr1.c: In function 'main':
pr1.c:54:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'b
zero' [enabled by default]
C:\Users\rak\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMtb7Wt.o:pr1.c:(.text+0xc9): undefined refe
rence to `inet_pton'
C:\Users\rak\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMtb7Wt.o:pr1.c:(.text+0xe2): undefined refe
rence to `bzero'
C:\Users\rak\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMtb7Wt.o:pr1.c:(.text+0x1b5): undefined ref
erence to `bzero'
C:\Users\rak\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMtb7Wt.o:pr1.c:(.text+0x224): undefined ref
erence to `bzero'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\rak\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMtb7Wt.o: bad reloc address 0x20 in section `.eh_frame'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link
 failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <string.h>
```

The error message tells you that gcc has `bzero` as a built-in function. But without a prototype in scope, your usage is considered to refer to a function that returns an `int` (the default return-type). So it doesn't match the built-in function, and gcc just passes the buck to the linker which similarly finds no such function. Add the header file so the compiler finds the correct prototype.

You might need to *enable* `bzero` with something like:

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
```

If that doesn't get rid of the `bzero` errors, then really you should ditch it and use `memset`.

For `inet_pton`, you'll also need:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

This note about sockets programming on windows might also be useful: [from Beej's Guide](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#windows).

Comment: It is not running even after adding #include <string.h>

Comment: no, I used BSD_SOURCE and I'm currently using <arpa/inet.h> as header file. But the errors are still same

Comment: It would help to see the code so I can stop suggesting what you've already tried.

Comment: But now 1 error is coming, that too of "inet_top" and I'm not able to resolve it.

Comment: Do you mean `inet_pton`? (Use ```backticks``` for code in comments.) If so, take a look at the link in @Shahbaz's answer for the windows equivalent.

Comment: yes, I'm talking about "inet_ntop". There is an alternative as mentioned in the link, but I'm still unable to resolve it. How to convert it to "wsaStringToAddress". I've tried various ways but not able to resolve

Answer (score 1):

`bzero` was a non-standard function, it is deprecated and removed from POSIX 2008. From man page of `bzero`:

> **CONFORMING TO**
>         4.3BSD.  This function is deprecated (marked as LEGACY in POSIX.1-2001): use memset(3) in new programs.  POSIX.1-2008 removes the specification of bzero().

So as cnicutar [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15966381/912144), you should use `memset` instead:

```
memset(ptr, 0, sizeof *ptr);
```

As a side note, pay attention to the fact that if the destination of `ptr` contains pointers, then the above `memset` doesn't make the pointers NULL, but just 0, which *could* be different from NULL.

In case of a `struct`, best way would be something like this:

```
struct something
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char *c;
    int d;
};

struct something var;
...
var = (struct something){0};  /* or NULL if first argument is a pointer */
/* or alternatively */
var = (struct something){ .a = 0 };
```

For an array of `struct`s, the most standard way would be a `for` loop followed by zeroing the `struct` as I mentioned above.

---

Regarding the `inet_pton` function, perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13731243/912144) could help you, suggesting use of the `WSAAddressToString` function.

Comment: Now only 1 error is coming, that too of "inet_top" and I'm not able to resolve it

Comment: @rahulkapoor, which error is coming? For `inet_top`, I'm afraid I won't be able to help you, but the question I linked to seems to have the answer. If you still can't figure it out, consider asking another question specifically about `inet_top` in windows, mentioning that you have seen the question I linked to, but it hasn't solved your problem.

Comment: yes, I'm talking about "inet_ntop". There is an alternative as mentioned in the link, but I'm still unable to resolve it. How to convert it to "wsaStringToAddress". I've tried various ways but not able to resolve.

Comment: @rahulkapoor, I'm afraid I have no idea. Like I said, try asking another question regarding that specific conversion.